# Can't set asset as datasource in the mediaplayer

Tags: android, datasource, media-player

I'm currently building a soundboard app as my first little Android app project.
I saved a bunch of .mp3 files in the assets folder of my app and then dynamically created buttons based on the .mp3 files stored in there. In the tag of every button, I saved its corresponding .mp3 file name.

In the `onClick()` event of every button, I try to set the `DataSource` of a global `MediaPlayer` to the file from my assets. The `FileDescriptor` handles the openFd command flawlessly but the mediaPlayer can't set the DataSource.

The app just crashes, after executing that command. Here is the `OnClickListener`:

```
tempButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        mediaPlayer.release();
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(tag + ".mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

The logcat prints the following crash when executing the setDataSource() method:

```
05-22 16:23:45.191 4505-4505/com.development.alo.dasunterboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.development.alo.dasunterboard, PID: 4505
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1133)
        at com.development.alo.dasunterboard.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I took a look into the MediaPlayer.java because the crash seems to happen there.
It looks like the FileDescriptor not valid.

Comment: `The App just crashes` see the exception stacktrace for the reason why it crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: It won&#39;t even get there.. I set a break point to the e.printStackTrace but before it gets there, the app instantly closes.

Comment: `the app instantly closes` and what does logcat say? You catch IOException, but there might other exception happen

Comment: I attached the logcat result of the crash. Have a look.

Comment: the problem is on the line `MainActivity.java:79`. What is on that line?

Comment: That is the following line in the OnClickListener() method:
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not `release()` MediaPlayer before setting DataSource, but should `reset()` it. Replase `mediaPlayer.release();` with `mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot mate!
When you read the Android API description about those two methods it also totally makes sense :)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html